# Can't run iPhone simulator - file "Logs" couldn't be saved

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator, xcode6.1

iPhone simulator doesn't work. Displays error message:

> The file “Logs” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Library” because a
>   file with the same name already exists.

When /Logs dir is empty, simulator creates subdir CoreSimulator/[AppID]  and dispalys the above message. It's fresh OS X Yosemite, installed on new Mac Mini.

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: This is more related to Ask Different rather than SO.

Answer (score 66):

Try to reset the Ios Simulator settings it worked for me!

iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

Answer (score 6):

**Just to make it more clear** (In addition to @storm's answer):

[image]

Comment: Where is this simulator? Inside Xcode? I am facing the same problem here.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/2B863330-D5E8-4DB4-B63E-599E290B3845/system.log'
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run ios --buildFlag=-UseModernBuildSystem=0 -lc (exit code 1).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you manually deleted ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator and the error message is because the sim is failing to create the ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Library/Logs symlink because it already exists.

You should be able to get out of this situation by resetting the device by running 'xcrun simctl erase [udid]'

Answer (score 2):

I solved this (Xcode 7.1) with:

```
find ~/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices -name Logs* -exec rm -fr {} \;
```