# Swift 2 Xcode 7.2.1 Playground Error - File "Logs" couldn't be saved in the folder "Library"

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcode7.2

When I created a new Playground file there is an error that says **"The file “Logs” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Library” because a file with the same name already exists."**. Same thing happens when I open an existing playground file.

The error only happens in Playground, no errors in any Project file.

I did my research and followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27661598/cant-run-iphone-simulator-file-logs-couldnt-be-saved) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073). I did restart my laptop after following everything on those two tutorials but still errors are still there.

I did not delete *~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode* yet as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073) since this is a huge file and I'm still not sure if this would work.

Check my screenshot below.
[image]

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: I did delete it and did a restart but the error still pops up everytime I open playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this answer [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/95139#95139) and I hope this helps.

1. Reboot your machine (and do not use Xcode yet - otherwise there might be errors later)
2. Delete the contents of ~/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices (typically it contains a directory with a name which is the UDID of the simulated device)
3. Start Xcode and open an iOS playground. This recreated the contents of ~/Library/Developer/XCPGDevices.